# How do I write Applescript to use hotkeys to control VLC Media Player in the background while typing on Word or Pages?

Tags: applescript, hotkeys

I would like to control VLC Media Player using hotkeys while typing in Word or Pages (without having to have VLC Media Player be the active window).

Can I use AppleScript to do this? I am editing video transcripts and, at the moment, have to toggle between programs to control the active window. I would love to be able to press hotkeys to:

- rewind
- jump back 5 seconds
- play/pause
- fast forward
- jump forward 5 seconds

Thank you so much for any help you can offer. I've never used AppleScript and appreciate any help.

---

I used a free hotkey assigner called Spark and inserted Applescript for these functions, following a tutorial on how to do this for transcription, but it didn't work. (I did it for Quicktime but would actually prefer to use VLC Media Player. Either would be great, though).

https://www.engadget.com/2008-06-26-simplify-media-transcription-with-hotkeys-and-applescript.html

Jump back:

tell document 1 of application "QuickTime Player" to set current time to (current time - 2500)

Play/pause:

tell document 1 of application "QuickTime Player"
if playing is true then
pause
else
start
end if
end tell

Jump forward:

tell document 1 of application "QuickTime Player" to set current time to (current time + 2500)

Comment: The terminology of any given application is entirely up to the developer, and are not guaranteed to be the same or provide the same functionality in another application.  You will need to look at VLC’s scripting dictionary to see the terms it provides.

Comment: The article you linked to is from 2008. Since then, Apple has tightened security around one app controlling another app. Spark might be the problem, so I’d try Keyboard Maestro or Fast Scripts instead.